# Do I have to import (duplicate) src libraries for multiple html pages over again to get their functionalities?

Tags: html, firebase, webpack, import, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase app and auth library that I import on my index.html mainpage via CDN links only.
I use it for logging in to my main page (some js code in `<script>` section).
Then, I have a second page somewhere, this page should have guarded resources, depending on the login status from firebase.
To check the login status on the second page, I would have to rely on firebase auth sdk again (from first html page), so would I have to import the src sdk file again in the `<head>` of the second page, right?

Is there some other / better way without reusing the same code or importing the same files from CDN again?

I probably could store the token or other user data in localStorage and send it to firebase resource on every request I guess, but is there another way?

Otherwise, I would have to use bundlers, like webpack is that correct ? (I guess thats part of the sense of what bundlers do?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your page pages loads completely independently of each other (unless you're building a SPA, which it sounds like you are not).  In that case, you do need to add the scripts you need to use on each page.  A prior page load will not automatically include the scripts on the next page.

A bundler will help you combine scripts for use on multiple pages, but each of those pages still has to load the bundled scripts on each load.

Comment: ok thanks, yes I am not using SPA Framework or so, just html css and vanilla js. But if each page still has to load the bundled scripts, there is no advantage of an extra bundler like webpack in that case, right? (except maybe spare you time writing more code). Btw, I noticed its always you editing or reviewing my posts first, how's that? :D

Comment: It's up to you to decide if a bundler has an advantage in your case.  Their purpose is not to eliminate the script includes you have across web pages.  They don't prevent you from having to include scripts on each page as needed.  Their purpose is to reduce the total volume of code that you have to include in each page.